# split.EOL give different results in Windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, split, eol

I am trying to split and join multiple line CSS values into a single line. For eg, we have the background-image property in CSS files. Sometimes that property value will have several linear-gradient values. Like below:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(
right,
#000 0%,
#fff 20%,
#ccc 40%,
#ddd 60%,
#fff 80%,
#000 100%
)
```

In this above example, the background-image value is split into multiple lines. So, what I am trying to do is use this below JS in REACT to join those lines into a single line for a specific purpose. This code works fine on some Windows machines:

```
const EOL = require('os');

console.log(getfile.split(EOL));
```

In this above JS, the getfile string contains multiple CSS file properties and values and returns this:

**Console log Results in Most of the Windows Machine:**

```
[
'background-image: linear-gradient(',
'right,',
'#000 0%,',
'#fff 20%,',
'#ccc 40%,',
'#ddd 60%,',
'#fff 80%,',
'#000 100%',
')'
]
```

**Console log Results in One Windows Machine:**

```
    [
    'background-image: linear-gradient(\n' +
    'right,\n' +
    '#000 0%,\n' +
    '#fff 20%,\n' +
    '#ccc 40%,\n' +
    '#ddd 60%,\n' +
    '#fff 80%,\n' +
    '#000 100%\n' +
    ')'
    ]
```

This `split.(EOL)` works on most of the Windows machines. But, it didn't work properly on one. You can check the console results. There is an **\n** text added in each line and then **+ (plus)** sign instead of **, (comma)** in that specific version of Windows. Due to this result, it didn't join the multiple line codes into single line.

I am not sure why it occurs in that specific Windows machine..

FYI: Both windows machine node versions are above 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `os.EOL` depends on the platform: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/os.html#os_os_eol. So in your case you should rely not on `os.EOL` but rather use the actual line-endings of the file you are working with. Now whether \n or \n\r is determined by your editor. For instance, VSCode supports both \n and \n\r. One of the reasons CSS files might have different line endings on different machines might be autocrlf option in Git if that is what you use. Basically, Git may be configured to transform \n to \n\r on checkout. Confirm whether that is true and do not rely on `os.EOL` since it only gives you *expected* line endings on the current platforms, which is not necessarily what a given file uses.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `getfile.split(/\r?\n/);`. This will parse newlines regardless of the platform/OS.